# Removing a javascript from a html page dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dynamically loaded a javascript by using :

```
  var fileref=document.createElement('script')

  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")

  fileref.setAttribute("src", "../scripts/sample.js");

  $("head").append(fileref);
```

Now to remove/unload the script the reverse doesr not work as a script once executed in a browser cannot be removed.

Is there a solution/workaround to this.?

Comment: what did you use to remove? And after appending, why you want to remove it again?

Comment: after remove the appended script you should set to null all object instance and appended event handlers

Comment: No. Once a script is loaded, the objects and functions it defines are kept in memory. Removing a script element does not remove the objects it defines.

Comment: The script is clashing with other scripts loaded and therefore needs to be removed after a certain functionality.

Comment: It's not going to stop clashing just because you remove the script element.

Comment: How to remove the elements loaded in memory also so that the removed script has no effect

Comment: Once you run the script, it is loaded in memory. Hence removing it from the HTML  code has absolutely no effect. If you wish to load javascript dynamically, i suggest you have a look at www.createjs.com/#!/PreloadJS

Comment: After removing the script ,the elements loaded in memory has no effect....can there be a workaround for this?>

Comment: Explain what you're actually trying to accomplish.  It can probably be done, but unloading the script element will not do it.

Comment: Do you control the code in the script and can you describe in more detail what you mean by "clashing with other scripts"?

Comment: I have multiple scripts on my html page like prettyScroll.js , datepicker.js but these two are clashing and the scroll is displayed wrongly because of this so i am trying to dynamically load and unload the datepicker.js on requirement so that others are not affected

Comment: wait, do you want to "load and unload the datepicker.js", does that mean do you want to change the order? if so, why don't you just modify the markup? are all the scripts loaded dynamically?

Comment: Notice, that you can remove the HTMLScriptElements, but the scripts remain, they can still be executed. And: __you can't remove the script itself__, there's no way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove elements using [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.removeChild):

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

//removing it from the head, where you added them
head.removeChild(script);
```

---

OR

As per your explanation in comments section try this solution :-

```
var fileref=document.createElement('script');

fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");

fileref.setAttribute("src", "../scripts/sample.js");

fileref.setAttribute("id","scid");         //<-------add 'id' to script

$("head").append(fileref);
```

and then remove script with `id` as shown :

```
var element = document.getElementById("scid");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Comment: The elements are once loaded in the browser are still there  so the remove Child did not work.

Comment: @user3713816..try using single quotes as head.removeChild('script');

Comment: i am using id instead of 'script' as there are more than one script in head and i only want to remove 1

Comment: @user3713816..plz update question and make clear what you actually want..above answer will work fine..

Comment: the above method did'nt work....even after removing the script tag, the elements are still loaded in browser memory hence clash happens

Comment: @user3713816..you cannot remove js files from script tag as pointed by teemu in above comment correctly above shown answer is a workaround whick works correctly..

Comment: ok..thanks..as i can remove script but script element are still persisting so i will have to find another workaround for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the script like this:

```
$('script[src$="sample.js"]').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier to do it with `jquery.js`

### 1. Remove all Scripts

```
$('script').remove()
```

### OR

### 2. Remove Specific Scripts

```
$('script').each(function(node){
   if (node.src == 'abc.js'){ # Check whether or not you want to remove it. 
       node.remove();
   }
}
```